# Transition not smooth in bootstrap card

Tags: html, sass, css-transitions, bootstrap-5

I've been creating a website with some cards containing a full background image using bootstrap and scss. However the hover transition I made isn't smooth on the edges. I have tried removing the expansion of the image and this makes it work but I can't seem to get them to work properly together.

[jSFiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/1se7p3xc/31/)

My code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="py-5">
        <div class="row" id="card-row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="card-wrapper">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img
                     src="https://i1.wp.com/potafiori.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/placeholder.png?ssl=1"
                     class="card-img"
                     alt="placeholder_img"
                     />
                <div
                     class="card-img-overlay text-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overlay-dark"
                     >
                  <div
                       class="card-content-container d-flex flex-column align-items-center"
                       >
                    <h5
                        class="card-title"
                        style="
                               font-size: 18px;
                               font-weight: bold;
                               min-height: 42px;
                               "
                        >
                      Heading
                    </h5>
                    <a href="{{ servizio.slug }}/" class="btn btn-primary"
                       >Find Out More!</a
                      >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    grid-column: 2 / 3 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  
  main {
    display: grid !important;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(1rem, 1fr) minmax(min-content, 70rem) minmax(

---

---

      1rem,
      1fr
    ) !important;
    row-gap: 3rem !important;

    #card-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;

      display: inline-block;

      &::after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        padding-top: 100%;
      }

      .card {
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: 1s;
        border-radius: 20px !important;

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;

        width: 100%;

        img {
          transition: 1s;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          object-fit: cover;
          object-position: center;
        }

        .overlay-dark {
          background-color: rgba(black, 0.5);
          transition: 1s;

          .card-content-container {
            height: 30px;
            transition: 1s;

            .btn {
              visibility: hidden;
              transition: 1s;
            }
          }
        }

        &:hover {
          transform: scale(1.1);

          .overlay-dark {
            background-color: rgba(black, 0.35);

            .card-content-container {
              height: 100px;

              .btn {
                visibility: visible;
              }
            }
          }

          img {
            transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-3deg);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems to working pretty smooth for me in your fiddle. You are using `bootstrap 4` in your code, but you tagged question with `bootstrap 5`. I have small hunch if your having css transition glitches in your project, is that you are using `#card-wrapper` more than once. You can only use id's once, so if you have multiple cards using `#card-wrapper` more than once... then switch `#card-wrapper` to a class... `.card-wrapper`. What browser are you testing in btw?